# Cannot connect NFS server with Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nfs

I'm trying to mount NFS server (it is set up in Azure Virtual Machine) inside the Kubernetes cluster (AKS).

Basically I fallowed this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-nfs-volume

All seemed to be good so far. I've tested the connection from pod to the NFS machine with telnet `telnet IP_ADDRESS_NFS_MACHINE 111` and `telnet IP_ADDRESS_NFS_MACHINE 2049`. Telnet connected.

But for some reason I'm getting error when the pod is starting:
`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "aks-nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32`
And the most important part:
`Output: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting IP_ADDRESS:/export/data`

I guess it is permissions issue. I tried to use `securityContext` in deployment k8s object. I've set `fsGroup` to `33` as I thought that because my application is running under apache server that would be good GID attached. I'm not sure about this part though.
The exported part from the NFS server `/export/data` - I chowned it to www-data:www-data and it has 777 in terms of chmod. But still the issue persists.

Here's my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 33
      containers:
        - name: web
          image: the_image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-pv
              mountPath: /var/www/html/storage
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

My pvc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: nfs
```

And pv:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: aks-nfs
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: xx.xxx.xx.xx
    path: /export/data
```

My exports config file:

```
/export        10.240.0.0/16(rw,async,insecure,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
/export        localhost(rw,async,insecure,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
```

I'm not sure actually what is the process owner who connected with the mounted NFS.
Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: Can you add output for `kubectl get pv aks-nfs`and `kubectl get pvc nfs-pvc`?

Answer (score 0):

The `pv` definition is not correct.
You don't have to define that export.

Modify the `pv` as per this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: aks-nfs
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: xx.xxx.xx.xx
    path: /export
```

And also on `pvc` use the same name defined in `pv`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: aks-nfs 
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: nfs
```

Once modified the files, reapply them with `kubectl`.